# How can i increase the URL length

Tags: openstreetmap, matching, osrm

On OSRM I try to match 500 locations by url, but get the error below:

> Request-URI Too Long 
> The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
> Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80

Answer (score 1):

You can try POST requests instead of GET, that should work according to this issue:

https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/1293

If you are hosting the OSRM instance yourself, you can also [increase the limit in Apache](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-fix-414-request-uri-too-large-in-apache/) by increasing the configs:

```
LimitRequestLine 10000
LimitRequestFieldSize 4000
```

Comment: HTTP POST is [not supported](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/pull/2182) by OSRM backend API. Besides increasing the Apache limits you will have to use the `--max-matching-size` parameter for osrm-routed as described at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/458227/222231